# Assigning last number to first number and vice versa

Tags: c, algorithm, variable-assignment

If I have numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and whenever I get the value 7 then I will change the value to 1 and if I get 6 then I will change it to 2 and if I get 2 then I will change the value as 6 and so on. I can easily do this with array but can I want to know the logic by without using array.

Comment: Umm.. `newNumber = 8 - oldNumber`?

Comment: Start by writing down a few of the relations you want to implement, on paper perhaps, you know `7->1,6->2,2->6`, then suck the end of your pencil while you work out the rule.

Answer (score 3):

For any number sequence `1,2,3,...,n`, just return `n+1-i`, where `i` is a given number.